# Measuring value added per capita technique (Macroeconomics)

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, econometrics, gdp, economic-growth

I am reading this [paper](https://academic.oup.com/wbro/article/36/2/164/5813434#271177670), and in the methods section, the authors define manufacturing value added per capita as, "For example, manufacturing value added per capita is equivalent to manufacturing value added in constant prices divided by the number of manufacturing workers, multiplied by the share of the population working in the sector.."

I am curious why don't the authors simply divide the manufacturing value by the total workers employed in the sector, rather than doing that and then multiplying it by the share of workers in the same sector?

Comment: Manufacturing value added per manufacturing worker is total manufacturing value added divided by the number of manufacturing workers.  Manufacturing value added per capita population is total manufacturing value added divided by the total population, but is therefore also equal to manufacturing value added per manufacturing worker multiplied by the share of the total population working in manufacturing.

Comment: So the latter method tells us more about the employment contribution of the sector (e.g. manufacturing) relative to the employed population, correct?

Comment: I have not read the paper in full, but it seems to be looking at growth in this indicator, and may be interested in the components of changes in manufacturing value added, manufacturing workers and population, or of changes in the relevant ratios of these.

Comment: Clear, thanks for the clarification.